# Continuar animación después de que el evento hover acabe CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy diseñando una pagina web y necesito hacer una animación para cuando pasas el mouse por encima de una imagen y que esta gire, logre hacer que gire pero la animación se detiene nada mas muevo el mouse fuera de la imagen
tengo esto:

```css
.profilepic {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

.profilepic:hover {
    animation: spin 1s alternate;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="profilepic" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Profile-Picture">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa `transition` en lugar de `animation`:

```css
.profilepic {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

.profilepic:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="profilepic" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Profile-Picture">
```

Usando tu código es posible lograrlo en combinación con javascript, detectando el final de la animación mediante un evento:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("profilepic");

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
    elements[i].classList.remove('animated');
  });

 elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
   elements[i].classList.add('animated')
 })
}
```

```css
.profilepic {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}

.animated {
    animation: spin 1s alternate;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="profilepic" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Profile-Picture">
```